# pyodbc - previous sql was not a query

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I get the above error while trying to insert data into a table, I tried the SET NOCOUNT ON option as well and still have the same problem,

```
import pyodbc as p

connstr= 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TEST;Trusted_Connection=yes;unicode_results=False'
conn = p.connect(connstr,charset='UTF-16')
print conn
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
    result = cursor.execute("""select col1 into tb2 from (select 1 as col1) tb1""")
except Exception as error:
    print error

for each in result.fetchall():
    print each
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute that first `select [xxx] into [new_tablename] from [yyy]` TSQL statement, then read from the newly created tb2 table.

```
import pyodbc as p

connstr= 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=TEST;Trusted_Connection=yes;unicode_results=False'
conn = p.connect(connstr,charset='UTF-16')
print conn
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
    result = cursor.execute("""select col1 into tb2 from (select 1 as col1) tb1""")
except Exception as error:
    print error

try:
    result = cursor.execute("""select col1 from tb2""")
except Exception as error:
    print error

for each in result.fetchall():
    print each
```

Also, you might want to change your instance name to `.\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `SQLEXPRESS`.